# How to determine if a file is 32 bits or 64 bits using Java APIs?

Tags: java

I have a file which is getting uploaded (a *.wim file which can be either 32 bits or 64 bits- WAIK/WADK).

The wim file is copied to a location.

Earlier we had only 32 bit support, but now for UEFI purpose, we need to support both 32 bits (for BIOS) and 64 bits (for UEFI).

Now, after the upload is done, the intention is based on the file type, i will copy it to either the 32 bit or 64 bit folder.

How to discriminate it?

P.S: Removed the win tag as this is more a general determination of file type rather than the WIM.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what these files are: if the size is divisible by 4 and not 8 it is a 32bit file. Maybe it helps.

Comment: That definitely depends on the file type.

Comment: @Burkhard - But that only exists for one case - What if the file is divisible by both 4 and 8 (as a file with just one 64bit entry would be)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format - this one?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yeah, the same one.

Comment: IIUC, WIM is just a file system dump, unrelated to any architecture. Are you trying to find out if it contains 32-bit or 64-bit executables?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Exactly, we mount it and copy the files.

Comment: note that most files are neither 32-bit nor 64 bit. Textual formats are byte-oriented, most compressed streams are bit-oriented. The RAW image format can be stored in triples of bytes, or in bytes. The only architecture-specific files are native executables (and some image files in the wooden age of computing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we disregard the WIM issue and just consider finding the architecture, for which an exe file (Portable Executable) is compiled, this is relatively simple:

- The file must start with the two bytes 0x4d, 0x5a, equivalent to the ASCII encoding of the string "MZ".
- At offset 0x3c, read 4 bytes little-endian encoded to get the offset to the PE header.
- At offset "PE header", you should check for four bytes 0x50, 0x45, 0x00, 0x00, equivalent to the ASCII encoding of the string "PE\0\0".
- Immediately following the PE header, you will find a 20 bytes long COFF File Header. The machine type is encoded (little endian) in the two first bytes of the COFF header.

Relevant for your case are probably the machine types 0x014c (i386) and 0x8664 (AMD64).

For more details, you can get the PE specification from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg463125). The different machine types are listed in section 2.3.1.

You may also be interested in checking the characteristics field of the COFF header (last two bytes) to identify the file as an executable (as opposed to e.g. a DLL file).

Comment: Now, let's face the WIM issue :-)

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no Java library to read WIM files. If the Java software runs on a Windows machine, the easiest approach is probably to call the Windows tools from Java to mount the image to a temporary directory, access the content normally with java.io.File and then unmount the image.